# I can't drop a database in PostgreSQL 11

Tags: postgresql, drop-database

I have 5 databases which are shown below.

[image]

I am  trying to drop test database by using "drop database test". But when i check list of databases than test database also shown in that list.

[image]

What should I do now? 
How i can resolve this issue?

Comment: What happens if you run the command with a semicolon at the end? i.e. `DROP DATABASE test;` ?

Comment: postgres=# drop database test;
ERROR:  database "test" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There is 1 other session using the database.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you are missing the semi-colon. When psql changes from = to - in the prompt, it means you haven’t finished the query.

Comment: when i add semi-colon it give me error like this. postgres=# drop database test;
ERROR:  database "test" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There is 1 other session using the database.

Comment: Make sure there are no active connections. Any other clients connected to that database would cause that error.